# Turning a peer domain into the functional domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008

Quick question

I'm swapping an old domain controller for a newer system. The existing server is an x86 install of Windows Server 2k8 and I am moving all of the company's system to an x64 2008 R2 SP1 system.

Will I be able to cold connect the system to the network, create a peer domain, and copy all of the existing active directory and DNS settings over (minus DHCP, DFS, etc etc that's already configured) or will I run into an issue because one is an x86 install and the new install is x64.

I'm trying to prestage as much as possible without having to configure everything over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a DC promo and creating a peer DC. Left both controllers in for fault tolerance.

Thank you for your assistance in my other issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the new server and promote it to a Domain Controller, you just need to ensure you move any of the Floating Single Master Operations Roles (FSMO) from the server you wish to take to to the new server (or to another appropriate server) on the network.

To determine what if any FSMO roles a server is responsible for, see the following -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234790

Comment: There will be no underlying issue with x86 and x64?